# I want Core Data search Query for User containing some mobile number

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have 2 Entities. User and Mobile. and have created the relationship also.
I want NSPredicate query, while user types the number the data should come from core data with number and that user name.

```
+(NSArray *)searchWithNumber:(NSString *)string
{

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DataManager sharedManager]managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Mobile class])];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[c] %@", @"number", string];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
User *user;
Mobile *mobile;
NSMutableArray *arrayTempMobile = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{
    mobile = (Mobile *)[array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",mobile.number);

    [arrayTempMobile addObject:mobile.number];
}

}
```

this is the code. so i m getting numbers only. but i want user name too.

Answer (score 2):

You have a relationship between the mobile and the user so you can navigate it to get the name, like:

```
mobile.user.name
```

Comment: can you give me Proper NSPredicate ? please

Comment: please help. I want to fetch the data from typing mobile number which is in String format.

Comment: @DeepalPatel whats your problem to access mobile.user.name? Where did you copy this code from?

Comment: How to put this in NSPRedicate ?

Comment: there is no predicate, you already have the mobile object and you're just getting some other data from it, which happens to be at the other end of a relationship.